# Batch File Won't Run Correctly

Tags: batch-file

I made a batch file that does not work, so I need your help to fix it.
I put these lines of code into notepad,

```
@echo off
wmic
quit
cls
netsh wlan show profiles
netsh wlan show profiles **My Wifi Name** key=clear
pause
```

saved it as "All Files", and titled it as pass.bat . But when I run the program it doesn't do anything. I want to automatically run these commands that are in the code I showed you.
Please give me the correct lines of code to make into a .bat file. 
Thank You! -Caden

Comment: What is your output for this? http://pastebin.com/bNsV2sPC

Comment: what's wmic supposed to do? the 'quit' is definitively not passed to wmic, it's processed after wmic returns the control to the batch file. then you'll get a syntax error because 'quit' is not a nt-cmd command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the call to `wmic`. It will start the program in the current console and wait for user interaction, the `quit` will not be readed from the batch file until the `wmic` command ends.

Remove the call to `wmic` (it seems it is doing nothing), or, if there is a reason to keep it, change to

```
@echo off
    echo quit | wmic
    cls
    ....
```

that will pipe the `quit` string to the started `wmic`

Comment: Okay,  Thanks This Answered My Problem